# Calculating the time difference between table rows to get the duration

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table in big query which pulls in data on a daily basis about call centre agent activity. I want to be able to calculate the time difference on each row from the following time stamp which will give me the duration of each line and store it in a duration field in the same time. After much effort try to work this out I am posting a question here looking for help. It probably quite simple but I can't quite it out.

| Row | Timestamp | AgentID | Type | TaskID | Intent | Action | Change | URL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 90 | 1616982416912 | 3 | navigation | 1457 | Not Set | Not Set | domainChange | https://askyourteam-my.sharepoint.com/_forms/default.aspx |
| 91 | 1616982725265 | 3 | navigation | 1457 | Not Set | Not Set | domainChange | https://www.stuff.co.nz/ |
| 92 | 1616983270822 | 3 | navigation | 1457 | Not Set | Not Set | domainChange | http://www.uxhoney.com/ |

Therefore the outcome will look like this.. (*note I have not actually calculated the time in this extra column for this example. The numbers are just placeholder examples.

| Row | Timestamp | AgentID | Type | TaskID | Intent | Action | Change | URL | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 90 | 1616982416912 | 3 | navigation | 1457 | Not Set | Not Set | domainChange | https://askyourteam-my.sharepoint.com/_forms/default.aspx | 155* (assuming this was calculated from row 89) |
| 91 | 1616982725265 | 3 | navigation | 1457 | Not Set | Not Set | domainChange | https://www.stuff.co.nz/ | 1800* |
| 92 | 1616983270822 | 3 | navigation | 1457 | Not Set | Not Set | domainChange | http://www.uxhoney.com/ | 134* |

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: what is expected result?

Comment: Ideally I would create a new field call duration and this would be a calculated field which in each row is the difference between for example row 91 and 90.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below

```
select *, 
  (Timestamp - lag(Timestamp) over prev_row) duration
from `project.dataset.table`
window prev_row as (partition by AgentID order by Timestamp)
```

Most likely you want to calculate duration for each agent separately - so I added `partition by AgentID` - but you should decide what exactly partitioning you need

Answer (score 0):

If I undertand correctly you can use lag() window function to achieve that :

```
select * , TIMESTAMP_DIFF(Timestamp,PrvTimestamp, MINUTE)  
(
  select * , LAG(Timestamp) over (order by Row) PrvTimestamp
  from table
) tt
```